# Subgroups of a group of order $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that a group, $G$, of order $p^n$ has subgroups of order $p^{i}$ for all $i \in \{1,2,3,\text{} \dots n\}$.
I have recently read that such a group also has normal subgroups of order $p^{i}$ for all $i \in \{1,2, \dots n\}$.

So is every group of order $p^{i}$ normal in $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a group $G$ of order $p^n$, with $p$ prime, it *is* necessarily true that there exist normal subgroups of order $p^i$, but it is *not* necessarily true that *every* subgroup of order $p^i$ is normal in $G$.

**Example**:

The dihedral group of order $8 = 2^3$ has a subgroup of order $2$ that is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: Funny. It appears that three people posted with exactly the same counterexample at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the dihedral group $D$ of order $8$. It has a subgroup of order $2$ that is not normal in $D$. Explicitly, let $r$ and $f$ be its generators with $r$ having order $4$ and $f$ having order $2$. Then $H=\langle f\rangle$ is not a normal subgroup of $D$, since $r^{-1}fr=r^{-2}f$, which is not an element of $H$.

Comment: Wow Karl, NICE!  I almost swore I accidentally entered my answer twice :-)

Comment: @Doc I was thirty seconds earlier. (Not sure if you're accusing me of plagiarism)

Comment: Hahaha ... maybe so.  But your solution only registered on my laptop at the exact same time.  I call it "net lag".  Oh, I should add, plaguerism never crossed my mind.  I hope my comment didn't suggest that.

Comment: @Doc Ah, that was my only concern. I feel in no way superior because my answer was submitted earlier, and even more so because the margin was so small.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. Consider the dihedral group $D_4$ of order 8.  It has four reflections, each generating a subgroup of order $2$, and none of these subgroups is normal in $D_4$.